# Java - Hibernate could not initialize proxy - no session

Tags: java, hibernate

```
  public List getPayslipsOfEmployees(String empids, Date paydate) {
    initializeTransaction();

    String strSQL = "SELECT "
            + "          pd.* "
            + "        FROM "
            + "          payroll_d pd "
            + "          INNER JOIN "
            + "          payroll_h ph "
            + "          ON pd.pay_uid = ph.pay_uid "
            + "        WHERE pd.employee_id IN ("+empids+") "
            + "          AND ph.pay_date = DATE('"+sql_dateformat.format(paydate)+"')";
    SQLQuery q =  session.createSQLQuery(strSQL);
    q.addEntity("pd", PayrollD.class);
    List pdlist = q.list();
    commit();

    List<Payslip> pslips = new ArrayList<Payslip>();
    if (!pdlist.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator it = pdlist.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            try {
                                PayrollD payd = (PayrollD)it.next();

            Payslip ps = new Payslip();
            ps.setDepartment(payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getDepartmentCatalog().getDeptName());
            ps.setEmployeeID(payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getEmployeeId());
            ps.setEmployeeName(payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getEmpLastname(), payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getEmpFirstname(), payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getEmpMiddlename());
            ps.setStartPayPeriod(payd.getPayrollH().getPayFromdate());
            ps.setEndPayPeriod(payd.getPayrollH().getPayTodate());
            ps.setDesignation(payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getJobDesignation());

            EmployeeExemption exmptn = (EmployeeExemption)getCurrentExemption(payd.getEmployeeCatalog().getEmployeeId());
            ps.setExemption((exmptn != null) ? exmptn.getExemptionCode() : SysConstants.DEFAULT_EXEMPTION);

            List<PayslipEarning> earnings = new ArrayList<PayslipEarning>();
            List<PayslipDeduction> deductions = new ArrayList<PayslipDeduction>();

            ps.setNetPay(getPayslipNetPay(payd, earnings, deductions));
            ps.setPrevTotalTaxableEarning(getPrevTotalTaxableEarning(payd));
            ps.setTotalWithheld(getTotalWithheld(payd));

            ps.setEarnings(earnings);
            ps.setDeductions(deductions);

            pslips.add(ps);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Somethings wrong " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }
    return pslips;
}
```

> I am getting this function by this funtion

```
  private void generatePaySummary() {
    try {
        Map params = new HashMap();
    params = getOrganizationInfo(params);
    params.put("rptsubtitle", "Payroll Date: "+date_formatter.format(tbpaydate.getDate()));

    int i = cboDept.getSelectedIndex();
    int deptno = 0;
    if (i != -1)  deptno = (Integer)deptnos.get(i);

    ReportService srv = new ReportService();
    List empids = srv.getEmployeesInPayroll(deptno, tbpaydate.getDate());
    if (!empids.isEmpty()) {
        PayslipService.setEmployees(empids);
        PayslipService.setPayDate(tbpaydate.getDate());

        RepGenService repsrv = new RepGenService();
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource jbsrc = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(PaySummaryFactory.getPaySummary());
        repsrv.generateReport(false, "/orgpayroll/reports/jasper/payrollsummary.jasper", true, params, jbsrc);
    }
    else
        SysUtils.messageBox("No employees in payroll on "+date_formatter.format(tbpaydate.getDate())+"!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

When I try to run this function to get the payroll and employee information of the employee, it says Hibernate could not initialize proxy - no session. I can't find which one is causing the error. It works when I only process one employee of the same date, but when I process two employees on the same date, the error occurs.

Comment: How are declaring or getting `session`?!

Comment: I added the code that getting the session.